# Uniform convergence of a product

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ be a sequence that converges to $g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$ and let $g:[a,b]→R$ be continuous.

Show that $f_ng$ converges uniformly to $g^2$.

So for $ε>0$, $|f_n-g|<ε$.

$|f_ng-g^2|≤ |g||f_n-g|<|g|ε$

I am not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is bounded. So there exists some $C>0$ such that $|g(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: So could I change my original convergence to |fn−g|<(ε/C) so then |fng−g^2|≤|g||fn−g|<|g|(ε/C)<C(ε/C)<ε ?

Comment: Yes, exactly: choose $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-g(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{C}$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and all $n\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is continuous there exists $M\in \mathbb R$ such that  $$\|g\|=\sup \{|g(x):x\in [a,b]\}= M.$$  $$ \text {So } \quad\|f_ng-g^2|\leq \|f_n-g\|  M.$$ And $\|f_n-g\|\to 0,$ so $\|f_ng-g^2\|\to 0$ also.

Or, if you   prefer, for any $e>0$ there is $n$ such that $m\geq n\implies \|f_m-g\|<e/M.$  $$\text {So }\quad m \geq n \implies \|f_ng-g^2\||<\leq (e/M)\|g\|\leq (e/M)M=e.$$